# Char to Hex in javascript

Tags: javascript, char, hex

Could anyone guide me on how to convert char to hex in javascript?
For example:

> "入力されたデータは範囲外です。" 
> to
>   
> "\u5165\u529B\u3055\u308C\u305F\u30C7\u30FC\u30BF\u306F\u7BC4\u56F2\u5916\u3067\u3059\u3002"

[This site does it](http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/javaUnicode/converter.html)

However I can not figure it out.

Any suggestion.

Thanks, Sarbbottam

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can loop through the characters and use the `charCodeAt` function to get their UTF-16 values, then constructing a string with them.

Here's some code I constructed that is much better than the code on the site you've linked, and should be easier to understand:

```
function string_as_unicode_escape(input) {
    function pad_four(input) {
        var l = input.length;
        if (l == 0) return '0000';
        if (l == 1) return '000' + input;
        if (l == 2) return '00' + input;
        if (l == 3) return '0' + input;
        return input;
    }
    var output = '';
    for (var i = 0, l = input.length; i < l; i++)
        output += '\\u' + pad_four(input.charCodeAt(i).toString(16));
    return output;
}
```

Let's break it down.

1. `string_as_unicode_escape` takes one argument, `input`, which is a string.
2. `pad_four` is an internal function that does one thing; it pads strings with leading `'0'` characters until the length is at least four characters long.
3. Start off by defining `output` as an empty string.
4. For each character in the string, append `\u` to the `output` string. Take the UTF-16 value of the character with `input.charCodeAt(i)`, then convert it to a hexadecimal string with `.toString(16)`, then pad it with leading zeros, then append the result to the `output` string.
5. Return the `output` string.

As Tim Down commented, we can also add `0x10000` to the `charCodeAt` value and then `.slice(1)` the string resulting from calling `.toString(16)`, to achieve the padding effect.

Comment: Thank you very much. - Sarbbottam

Comment: You can lose the padding code with the following trick: `output += '\\u' + (input.charCodeAt(i) + 0x10000).toString(16).slice(1);`

Comment: That is very clever indeed ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
function string_as_unicode_escape(str){
    return str.split("").map(function(s){
        return "\\u"+("0000" + s.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
    }).join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var hex=new Array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f');

```
    function stringEncode()
    {
        var x=document.getElementById("from_text");


        var preescape="" + x.value;
        var escaped="";

        var i=0;
        for(i=0;i<preescape.length;i++)
        {
            escaped=escaped+encodeChar(preescape.charAt(i));
        }

        //x=document.getElementById("to_text");

                    x.value=escaped;
        //alert("Codigo: "+escapeHtml(escaped));
        //document.getElementById('string_example').innerHTML="<b>String example with text</b><br/><br/>String s=\""+escapeHtml(escaped)+"\";<br/><br/>";
    }


    function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
       return unsafe
                .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
                .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
                .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
                .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
                .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
            }

            function encodeChar(original)
            {
                    var found=true;
                    var thecharchar=original.charAt(0);
                    var thechar=original.charCodeAt(0);
                    switch(thecharchar) {
                                    case '\n': return "\\n"; break; //newline
                                    case '\r': return "\\r"; break; //Carriage return
                                    case '\'': return "\\'"; break;
                                    case '"': return "\\\""; break;
                                    case '\\': return "\\\\"; break;
                                    case '\t': return "\\t"; break;
                                    case '\b': return "\\b"; break;
                                    case '\f': return "\\f"; break;

                                    default:
                                            found=false;
                                            break;
                            }
                            if(!found)
                            {
                                    if(thechar>127) {
                                            var c=thechar;
                                            var a4=c%16;
                                            c=Math.floor(c/16); 
                                            var a3=c%16;
                                            c=Math.floor(c/16);
                                            var a2=c%16;
                                            c=Math.floor(c/16);
                                            var a1=c%16;
                                    //  alert(a1);
                                            return "\\u"+hex[a1]+hex[a2]+hex[a3]+hex[a4]+"";        
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            return original;
                                    }
                            }


            }
```

//------------------------ lo llamarias con

Answer (score 0):

You can just use ordinary `replace()` for this.

```
'! \u0100 力 '.replace(
    /[^\x00-\xFF]/g,
    function(ch) {
        return ('\\u0' + ch.charCodeAt(0).toString(16))
            .replace(/0(?=....$)/, '');
    }
)
```

Produces `! \u0100 \u529b \ud83d\ude03`

Incredibly succinct, and handles the padding issue without cumbersome `if`s or slow `slice()`s.
Works [in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Browser_compatibility) unlike `map()`.
Note how it only replaces the characters you need to (`!` and  were untouched) without cumbersome iteration or slow `split()`ing.
Just as with the other answers, it also correctly handles surrogate pairs ( turned into the two bytes `\ud83d\ude03`).

Putting it in its own function and keeping the two regexes static would make it even faster again too if you're planning on reusing the function many times.

You can do all characters if you really need to by changing `[^\x00-\xFF]` to `.`, `\\u0` to `\\u000`, and `/0(` to `/0+(`.