# The hexadecimal from JavaScript and from the command line is different

Tags: javascript, hex

When I convert a file from text to hexadecimal with javascript I get this:

```
 3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 22 31
 2E 30 22 20 65 6E 63 6F 64 69 6E 67 3D 22 55 54
 46 2D 38 22 20 3F 3E A3 C7 27 37 32 07 66 57 27
 36 96 F6 E3 D2 23 22 E3 02 23 EA A3 C6 36 86 16
 E6 E6 56 C3 EA 20 20 3C 74 69 74 6C 65 3E 57 33
 53 63 68 6F 6F 6C 73 20 48 6F 6D 65 20 50 61 67
 65 3C 2F 74 69 74 6C 65 3E A2 02 03 C6 C6 96 E6
 B3 E6 87 47 47 07 33 A2 F2 F7 77 77 72 E7 73 37
 36 36 86 F6 F6 C7 32 E6 36 F6 D3 C2 F6 C6 96 E6
 B3 EA 20 20 3C 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6F 6E
 3E 46 72 65 65 20 77 65 62 20 62 75 69 6C 64 69
 6E 67 20 74 75 74 6F 72 69 61 6C 73 3C 2F 64 65
 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6F 6E 3E A2 02 03 C6 97 46
 56 D3 EA 20 20 20 20 3C 74 69 74 6C 65 3E 52 53
 53 20 54 75 74 6F 72 69 61 6C 3C 2F 74 69 74 6C
 65 3E A2 02 02 02 03 C6 C6 96 E6 B3 E6 87 47 47
 07 33 A2 F2 F7 77 77 72 E7 73 37 36 36 86 F6 F6
 C7 32 E6 36 F6 D2 F7 86 D6 C2 F7 86 D6 C5 F7 27
 37 32 E6 17 37 03 C2 F6 C6 96 E6 B3 EA 20 20 20
 20 3C 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6F 6E 3E 4E 65
 77 20 52 53 53 20 74 75 74 6F 72 69 61 6C 20 6F
 6E 20 57 33 53 63 68 6F 6F 6C 73 3C 2F 64 65 73
 63 72 69 70 74 69 6F 6E 3E A2 02 03 C2 F6 97 46
 56 D3 EA 20 20 3C 69 74 65 6D 3E A2 02 02 02 03
 C7 46 97 46 C6 53 E5 84 D4 C2 05 47 57 46 F7 26
 96 16 C3 C2 F7 46 97 46 C6 53 EA 20 20 20 20 3C
 6C 69 6E 6B 3E 68 74 74 70 73 3A 2F 2F 77 77 77
 2E 77 33 73 63 68 6F 6F 6C 73 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 78
 6D 6C 3C 2F 6C 69 6E 6B 3E A2 02 02 02 03 C6 46
 57 36 37 26 97 07 46 96 F6 E3 E4 E6 57 72 05 84
 D4 C2 07 47 57 46 F7 26 96 16 C2 06 F6 E2 05 73
 35 36 36 86 F6 F6 C7 33 C2 F6 46 57 36 37 26 97
 07 46 96 F6 E3 EA 20 20 3C 2F 69 74 65 6D 3E A3
 C2 F6 36 86 16 E6 E6 56 C3 EA A3 C2 F7 27 37 33
 EA
```

This is from the command line (`cat rss | od -A n -t x1`):

```
 3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 22 31
 2E 30 22 20 65 6E 63 6F 64 69 6E 67 3D 22 55 54
 46 2D 38 22 20 3F 3E 0A 3C 72 73 73 20 76 65 72
 73 69 6F 6E 3D 22 32 2E 30 22 3E 0A 0A 3C 63 68
 61 6E 6E 65 6C 3E 0A 20 20 3C 74 69 74 6C 65 3E
 57 33 53 63 68 6F 6F 6C 73 20 48 6F 6D 65 20 50
 61 67 65 3C 2F 74 69 74 6C 65 3E 0A 20 20 3C 6C
 69 6E 6B 3E 68 74 74 70 73 3A 2F 2F 77 77 77 2E
 77 33 73 63 68 6F 6F 6C 73 2E 63 6F 6D 3C 2F 6C
 69 6E 6B 3E 0A 20 20 3C 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74
 69 6F 6E 3E 46 72 65 65 20 77 65 62 20 62 75 69
 6C 64 69 6E 67 20 74 75 74 6F 72 69 61 6C 73 3C
 2F 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6F 6E 3E 0A 20 20
 3C 69 74 65 6D 3E 0A 20 20 20 20 3C 74 69 74 6C
 65 3E 52 53 53 20 54 75 74 6F 72 69 61 6C 3C 2F
 74 69 74 6C 65 3E 0A 20 20 20 20 3C 6C 69 6E 6B
 3E 68 74 74 70 73 3A 2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 77 33 73
 63 68 6F 6F 6C 73 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 78 6D 6C 2F 78
 6D 6C 5F 72 73 73 2E 61 73 70 3C 2F 6C 69 6E 6B
 3E 0A 20 20 20 20 3C 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69
 6F 6E 3E 4E 65 77 20 52 53 53 20 74 75 74 6F 72
 69 61 6C 20 6F 6E 20 57 33 53 63 68 6F 6F 6C 73
 3C 2F 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6F 6E 3E 0A 20
 20 3C 2F 69 74 65 6D 3E 0A 20 20 3C 69 74 65 6D
 3E 0A 20 20 20 20 3C 74 69 74 6C 65 3E 58 4D 4C
 20 54 75 74 6F 72 69 61 6C 3C 2F 74 69 74 6C 65
 3E 0A 20 20 20 20 3C 6C 69 6E 6B 3E 68 74 74 70
 73 3A 2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 77 33 73 63 68 6F 6F 6C
 73 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 78 6D 6C 3C 2F 6C 69 6E 6B 3E
 0A 20 20 20 20 3C 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6F
 6E 3E 4E 65 77 20 58 4D 4C 20 74 75 74 6F 72 69
 61 6C 20 6F 6E 20 57 33 53 63 68 6F 6F 6C 73 3C
 2F 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6F 6E 3E 0A 20 20
 3C 2F 69 74 65 6D 3E 0A 3C 2F 63 68 61 6E 6E 65
 6C 3E 0A 0A 3C 2F 72 73 73 3E 0A
```

The JavaScript:

```
const uploads = []

    const fileSelector = document.getElementById('file-selector')
    fileSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        console.time('FileOpen')
        const file = event.target.files[0]

        const filereader = new FileReader()

        filereader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
                const uint = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result)
                let bytes = []
                uint.forEach((byte) => {
                    bytes.push(byte.toString(16))
                })
                const hex = bytes.join('').toUpperCase()

                test=""
                for(var i=0; i<hex.length; i++) {
                   test += hex.charAt(i) + hex.charAt(i+1) + ' ';
                   i++
                }

                console.log(test);

            console.log("hex");
            console.log(hex);

                uploads.push({
                    filename: file.name,
                    filetype: file.type ? file.type : 'Unknown/Extension missing',
                    binaryFileType: getMimetype(hex, (file.type ? file.type : ''), file.name),
                    hex: hex
                })
                render()
            }

            console.timeEnd('FileOpen')
        }


        const blob = file; //file.slice(0, 300);
        console.log("blob");
        console.log(blob);
        console.log("read as text: ");
        //console.log(filereader.readAsText(blob));
        filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    })
 [...]
```

When I take the JS hex result and turn it back to text I get this mess:

��'72fW'6����#"�#��6���V��  W3Schools Home Page��Ɩ��GG3���wwr�s766����2�6����Ɩ��  Free web building tutorials�ƗFV��    RSS Tutorial��Ɩ��GG3���wwr�s766����2�6�����������'72�7��Ɩ��    New RSS tutorial on W3Schools����FV��  ��F�F�S���GWF�&����F�F�S�    https://www.w3schools.com/xml��FW67&�F�����Wr���GWF�&����s566����3��FW67&�F����  ���6���V����'73

I don't get that from the other hex.

So why is the hex different?

Comment: After fixing the issue elarmando described, you can just set `test = bytes.join(' ').toUpperCase()`.

Comment: Also, it might be a problem of [**encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448595/get-set-file-encoding-with-javascripts-filereader).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I am using `readAsArrayBuffer` does it change something? Because the example you shared is with `readAsText`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir there is no option for encoding for `readAsArrayBuffer` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer

Comment: @jnbdz Ah! I see. Sorry. I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that javascript convertion is not including the zeros on the left side. In case the convertion byte is one digit you must include a zero. For example, if convertion returns A, you must include the zero -> 0A

Comment: Ah! That actually explains other things! Too long to explain... Thanks